# Broken packages in upgrade

Tags: upgrade, package-management

I get this when trying to update Ubuntu 12.04

```
nobook@ubuntu:~$ apt-get dist-upgrade
E: No se pudo abrir el fichero de bloqueo «/var/lib/dpkg/lock» - open (13: Permission denied)
E: No se encontró un archivo de réplica «/var/lib/dpkg/»
nobook@ubuntu:~$ sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*
[sudo] password for nobook: 
rm: cannot remove `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial': Is a directory
nobook@ubuntu:~$ sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*
rm: cannot remove `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial': Is a directory
nobook@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get purge openjdk* 
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-dbg» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk7-jdk» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-doc» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-jre» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-demo» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-jdk» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-jre» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «uwsgi-plugin-jvm-openjdk-6» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-source» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-jre-lib» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «uwsgi-plugin-jwsgi-openjdk-6» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-jre-headless» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-jre-zero» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-source» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-demo» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-jre-zero» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-jre-lib» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-dbg» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-doc» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-jdk» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-jre» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-jre-headless» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
El paquete openjdk-6-dbg no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-6-demo no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-6-doc no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-6-jdk no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-6-source no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-6-jre-zero no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-dbg no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-demo no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-doc no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-jdk no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-jre no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-jre-headless no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-jre-lib no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-jre-zero no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-source no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete uwsgi-plugin-jvm-openjdk-6 no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete uwsgi-plugin-jwsgi-openjdk-6 no está instalado, no se eliminará
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt-get -f install» para corregirlo:
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 default-jre : Depende: openjdk-6-jre (>= 6b23~pre11-1ubuntu1~) pero no va a instalarse
 default-jre-headless : Depende: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b23~pre11-1ubuntu1~) pero no va a instalarse
 icedtea-6-jre-cacao : Depende: openjdk-6-jre-headless (= 6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) pero no va a instalarse
 icedtea-6-jre-jamvm : Depende: openjdk-6-jre-headless (= 6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) pero no va a instalarse
 icedtea-netx : Depende: openjdk-6-jre (>= 6b23~pre10~) pero no va a instalarse o
                         openjdk-7-jre pero no va a instalarse
 libdbus-1-3 : Rompe: libdbus-1-3:i386 (!= 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.3) pero 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4 va a ser instalado
 libdbus-1-3:i386 : Rompe: libdbus-1-3 (!= 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4) pero 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.3 va a ser instalado
E: Dependencias incumplidas. Intente «apt-get -f install» sin paquetes (o especifique una solución).
nobook@ubuntu:~$ apt-get -f install
E: No se pudo abrir el fichero de bloqueo «/var/lib/dpkg/lock» - open (13: Permission denied)
E: No se encontró un archivo de réplica «/var/lib/dpkg/»
nobook@ubuntu:~$ apt-get install
E: No se pudo abrir el fichero de bloqueo «/var/lib/dpkg/lock» - open (13: Permission denied)
E: No se encontró un archivo de réplica «/var/lib/dpkg/»
nobook@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get purge openjdk* 
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-dbg» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk7-jdk» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-doc» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-jre» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-demo» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-jdk» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-jre» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «uwsgi-plugin-jvm-openjdk-6» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-source» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-jre-lib» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «uwsgi-plugin-jwsgi-openjdk-6» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-jre-headless» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-jre-zero» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-source» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-demo» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-jre-zero» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-jre-lib» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-dbg» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-doc» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-jdk» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-6-jre» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
Nota, seleccionando «openjdk-7-jre-headless» para la expresión regular «openjdk*»
El paquete openjdk-6-dbg no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-6-demo no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-6-doc no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-6-jdk no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-6-source no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-6-jre-zero no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-dbg no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-demo no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-doc no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-jdk no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-jre no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-jre-headless no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-jre-lib no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-jre-zero no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete openjdk-7-source no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete uwsgi-plugin-jvm-openjdk-6 no está instalado, no se eliminará
El paquete uwsgi-plugin-jwsgi-openjdk-6 no está instalado, no se eliminará
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt-get -f install» para corregirlo:
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 default-jre : Depende: openjdk-6-jre (>= 6b23~pre11-1ubuntu1~) pero no va a instalarse
 default-jre-headless : Depende: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b23~pre11-1ubuntu1~) pero no va a instalarse
 icedtea-6-jre-cacao : Depende: openjdk-6-jre-headless (= 6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) pero no va a instalarse
 icedtea-6-jre-jamvm : Depende: openjdk-6-jre-headless (= 6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) pero no va a instalarse
 icedtea-netx : Depende: openjdk-6-jre (>= 6b23~pre10~) pero no va a instalarse o
                         openjdk-7-jre pero no va a instalarse
 libdbus-1-3 : Rompe: libdbus-1-3:i386 (!= 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.3) pero 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4 va a ser instalado
 libdbus-1-3:i386 : Rompe: libdbus-1-3 (!= 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4) pero 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.3 va a ser instalado
E: Dependencias incumplidas. Intente «apt-get -f install» sin paquetes (o especifique una solución).
nobook@ubuntu:~$
```

Any help?

Comment: Looks like a dependency problem, sorry I can't be of more help, don't speak Spanish

Comment: I would ask... why the `rm` at the start? Also, what package you want to uninstall? `openjdk`? Also, why are you running several instances of `apt`? Verify that your system isn't upgrading/updating and try again.

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, apt-get issues can involve multi-step solutions. From the error message, my suggestion would be to run `sudo apt-get -f install` to have apt-get try and fix it automatically.

If it succeeds, try the update again. If it doesn't, the error message might have clues about what to do next.

Comment: His problem is not by broken dependencies but by PIBCAK.